# How to delete multiple data entries in SQL database via tkinter?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I created an tkinter based app for users can make entries and modifying them if needed. This app interacts with SQLite for data storing purpose. However, I have an issue of deleting multiple data entries in SQL database via tkinter. You can check the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import backendv2

def get_selected_row(event):
    try:
        global selected_tuple
        index=list1.curselection()[0]
        selected_tuple=list1.get(index)
        e1.delete(0,END)
        e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
        e2.delete(0,END)
        e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[5])
        e9.delete(0,END)
        e9.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
        print(index)
    except IndexError:
        pass

def view_command():                             #View button function
    list1.delete(0,END)                         #Delete items in listbox
    for row in backendv2.view():                  #loop for getting data in SQLite database    
        list1.insert(END,row)              #Insert data to listbox

def search_command():                           #Search button function
    list1.delete(0,END)                         #Delete items in listbox    
    for row in backendv2.Search(Buildingcallsign_text.get()):         #loop for fetching data in SQLite database based on search value
        list1.insert(END,row)              #Insert data in listbox    

def add_command():                              #Add entry button function
    backendv2.calculate(Buildingcallsign_text.get(),AllPrisms.get(),NW_Prism.get(),NE_Prism.get(),SW_Prism.get(),\
                        SE_Prism.get(),NS_Distance.get(),WE_Distance.get(),Station_ID.get(),Variable_ID.get())      #Calculate and insert data to database based on user's entry

def delete_all():
    backendv2.drop()

def reconnect():
    backendv2.connect()

def Export_file():
    backendv2.export()

def delete_command():
    backendv2.delete(selected_tuple[0])

def update_command():
    backendv2.update(selected_tuple[0],Station_ID.get(),Buildingcallsign_text.get(),AllPrisms.get())


window=Tk()                 #Initiate the app

window.wm_title("Virtual Variable")             #Name of the App

l1=Label(window,text="Building callsign")       #Building callsign label
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)                         #Setup location for Building callsign label    

l2=Label(window,text="All Prisms")              #All Prisms label
l2.grid(row=0,column=2)                         #Setup location for All Prisms label

l3=Label(window,text="NW Prism")                #NW Prism label
l3.grid(row=1,column=0)                         #Setup location for NW Prism

l4=Label(window,text="NE Prism")                #NE Prism label
l4.grid(row=1,column=2)                         #Setup location for NE Prism

l5=Label(window,text="SW Prism")                #SW Prism label
l5.grid(row=2,column=0)                         #Setup location for SW Prism

l6=Label(window,text="SE Prism")                #SE Prism label
l6.grid(row=2,column=2)                         #Setup location for SE Prism

l7=Label(window,text="NS Distance")             #NS Distance label
l7.grid(row=3,column=0)                         #Setup location for NS Distance

l8=Label(window,text="WE Distance")             #WE Distance label
l8.grid(row=3,column=2)                         #Setup location for WE Distance

l9=Label(window,text="Station ID")              #Station ID label
l9.grid(row=4,column=0)                         #Setup location for Station ID

l10=Label(window,text="Variable ID")            #Variable ID label
l10.grid(row=4,column=2)                        #Setup location for Variable ID


Buildingcallsign_text=StringVar()               #Create a StringVar object
e1=Entry(window,textvariable=Buildingcallsign_text,width=40)    #Create Building callsign entry box widget
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)                         #Setup Building callsign entry box widget location

AllPrisms=StringVar()                           #Create a StringVar object
e2=Entry(window,textvariable=AllPrisms,width=40)    #Create AllPrisms entry box widget
e2.grid(row=0,column=3)                         #Setup AllPrisms entry box widget location

NW_Prism=StringVar()                            #Create a StringVar object
e3=Entry(window,textvariable=NW_Prism,width=40) #Create NW Prism entry box widget
e3.grid(row=1,column=1)                         #Setup location for NW Prism entry box widget

NE_Prism=StringVar()                            #Create a StringVar object
e4=Entry(window,textvariable=NE_Prism,width=40) #Create NE Prism entry box widget
e4.grid(row=1,column=3)                         #Setup location for NE Prism entry box widget

SW_Prism=StringVar()                            #Create a StringVar object
e5=Entry(window,textvariable=SW_Prism,width=40) #Create SW Prism entry box widget
e5.grid(row=2,column=1)                         #Setup location for SW Prism entry box widget

SE_Prism=StringVar()                            #Create a StringVar object
e6=Entry(window,textvariable=SE_Prism,width=40) #Create SE Prism entry box widget
e6.grid(row=2,column=3)                         #Setup location for SE Prism entry box widget

NS_Distance=StringVar()                         #Create a StringVar object
e7=Entry(window,textvariable=NS_Distance,width=40)  #Create Ns Prism entry box widget
e7.grid(row=3,column=1)                         #Setup location for NS Prism entry box widget

WE_Distance=StringVar()                         #Create a StringVar object
e8=Entry(window,textvariable=WE_Distance,width=40)  #Create WE Prism entry box widget
e8.grid(row=3,column=3)                         #Setup location for WE Prism entry box widget

Station_ID=StringVar()                          #Create a StringVar object
e9=Entry(window,textvariable=Station_ID,width=40)   #Create Station ID Prism entry box widget
e9.grid(row=4,column=1)                         #Setup location for Station ID Prism entry box widget

Variable_ID=StringVar()                         #Create a StringVar object
e10=Entry(window,textvariable=Variable_ID,width=40) #Create Variable ID Prism entry box widget
e10.grid(row=4,column=3)                        #Setup location for Variable ID Prism entry box widget

list1=Listbox(window, height=9,width=55, selectmode=EXTENDED)            #Create a listbox and setup its size
list1.grid(row=5,column=0,rowspan=7,columnspan=2)   #Setup listbox location

sb1=Scrollbar(window)                               #Create a vertical scrollbar for the listbox
sb1.grid(row=6,column=2,rowspan=4,sticky="NS")      #Setup the scrollbar's location and size - extends from top to bottom    

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)             #Attach the vertical scrollbar to the listbox
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)                  #Setup scrollbar for vertical scrolling

sb2=Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')          #Create a horizontal scrollbar for the listbox
sb2.grid(row=11,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky="WE")  #Setup the scrollbar's location and size - extends from left to right

list1.configure(xscrollcommand=sb2.set)             #Attach the horizontal scrollbar to the listbox
sb2.configure(command=list1.xview)                  #Setup scrollbar for horizontal scrolling

list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',get_selected_row)

b1=Button(window,text="Add Entry",width=12,command=add_command)         #Create the Add Entry button and assign to the add_command function above
b1.grid(row=5,column=3)                                                 #Setup the Add Entru button's location    

b2=Button(window,text="Search Entry",width=12, command=search_command)  #Create the Search Entry button and assign to the search_command above
b2.grid(row=6,column=3)                                                 #Setup the Search Entry button's location

b3=Button(window,text="View All",width=12,command=view_command)         #Create the View All button and assign to the view_command above    
b3.grid(row=7,column=3)                                                 #Setup the View All button's location

b4=Button(window,text="Update",width=12,command=update_command)                                #Create the Update button
b4.grid(row=8,column=3)                                                 #Setup the Update button's location    

b5=Button(window,text="Delete",width=12,command=delete_command)             #Create the Delete button
b5.grid(row=9,column=3)                                                 #Setup the Delete button's location

b6=Button(window,text="Export",width=12,command=Export_file)            #Create the Export button
b6.grid(row=10,column=3)                                                #Setup the Export button's location

b7=Button(window,text="Close",width=12,command=window.destroy)               #Create the Close button
b7.grid(row=11,column=3)                                                #Setup the Close button's location

window.mainloop()
```

Code for backendv2 module:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas
import csv
import re

def connect():                      #Function to create SQL database                                  
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")         #Establish connection to lite.db
    cur=conn.cursor()                       #Create cursor object in dataase
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calculation (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Station_ID INTEGER,Variable TEXT,\
                    Variable_ID INTEGER,Unit_ID INTEGER,Formula TEXT,RoC_Active INTEGER,RoC_Precision INTEGER,\
                    RoC_Period_Value INTEGER,RoC_Period_Type INTEGER,RoC_Unit_Value INTEGER,RoC_Unit_Type INTEGER,\
                    Datum_Variable_ID INTEGER,Datum_Timestamp TEXT,Datum_Information TEXT,Constants TEXT)")         #Create SQL table if it does not exist
    conn.commit()                   #Commit changes in database
    conn.close()                    #Close the connection to database

def calculate(Building_callsign,AllPrisms,NW_Prism,NE_Prism,SW_Prism,SE_Prism,NS_Distance,WE_Distance,Station_ID,Variable_ID):  #Function to calculate deformations and displacements
    VVListofLists=[]                            #Assign an empty list to VVListofLists
    VVList=[]                                   #Assign an empty list to VVList
    Tassgloname=Building_callsign + "Tass_Glo"  #Assign Tassgloname to the name of Tassement Global variable with corresponding to building's name
    ListAllPrisms=AllPrisms.split("+")          #Create a list with all Prisms in AllPrisms input box
    TasGLO="("+AllPrisms+")"+"/"+str(len(ListAllPrisms))        #Assign TasGLO as the calculation for Tassement Global
    VVList=[Station_ID,Tassgloname,Variable_ID,42,TasGLO]       #Put Station_ID,Tassgloname,Variable_ID,42,TasGLO into VVList of current input
    VVListofLists.append(VVList)                #Append VVList to VVListofLists

    if (NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="") or (NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!=""):      #Conditional for Tassement differentiel NS calculation is possible
        TasDifNSname=Building_callsign + "Tass_Diff_NS"                         #Assign TasDifNSname to the name of Tassement differentiel NS variable with corresponding to building's name
        
        if NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":     #Conditional for all prisms inputs are not empty
            TasDifNS="("+"("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"("+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)  #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism=="":       #Conditional for SE_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifNS="("+"("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance) #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism=="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NE_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifNS="("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"("+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)     #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS     
        
        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for SW_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifNS="("+"("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)     #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NW_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifNS="("+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+"-"+"("+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)     #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism=="" and SE_Prism=="":       #Conditional for NE_Prism and SE_Prism input boxes are empty
            TasDifNS="("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)       #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and SW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NW_Prism and SW_Prism input boxes are empty
            TasDifNS="("+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+"-"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)       #Assign TasDifNS as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel NS
        
        VVList=[Station_ID,TasDifNSname,Variable_ID,101,TasDifNS]           #Put Station_ID,TasDifNSname,Variable_ID,101,TasDifNS into VVList of current input
        VVListofLists.append(VVList)                #Append VVList to VVListofLists

    else:                   #Conditional for Tassement differentiel NS calculation is not possible
        TasDifNS=""         #Set TasDifNS as blank
        TasDifNSname=""     #Set TasDifNSname as blank

    if (NW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="") or (SW_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!=""):      #Conditional for Tassement differentiel OE calculation is possible
        TasDifOEname=Building_callsign + "Tass_Diff_OE"                         #Assign TasDifOEname to the name of Tassement differentiel OE variable with corresponding to building's name
        
        if NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":     #Conditional for all prisms inputs are not empty
            TasDifOE="("+"("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"("+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)   #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism=="":   #Conditional for SE_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifOE="("+"("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)     #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism=="" and SE_Prism!="":   #Conditional for NE_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifOE="("+"("+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)     #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE
        
        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":   #Conditional for SW_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifOE="("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"("+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)     #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":   #Conditional for NW_Prism input box is empty
            TasDifOE="("+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+"-"+"("+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+"+"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)     #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE

        elif NW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SW_Prism=="" and SE_Prism=="":   #Conditional for SW_Prism and SE_Prism input boxes are empty
            TasDifOE="("+"Z"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"Z"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)       #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism=="" and SW_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":   #Conditional for NW_Prism and NE_Prism input boxes are empty
            TasDifOE="("+"Z"+str(SW_Prism)+"-"+"Z"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)       #Assign TasDifOE as the calculation for Tassement Differentiel OE

        VVList=[Station_ID,TasDifOEname,Variable_ID,101,TasDifOE]           #Put Station_ID,TasDifOEname,Variable_ID,101,TasDifOE into VVList of current input
        VVListofLists.append(VVList)                #Append VVList to VVListofLists
        
    else:               #Conditional for Tassement differentiel OE calculation is not possible
        TasDifOE=""         #Set TasDifOE as blank
        TasDifOEname=""     #Set TasDifOEname as blank

    if (NW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="") or (SW_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!=""):          #Conditional for Deformation Horizontal NS calculation is possible
        DEHNSname=Building_callsign + "DEH_NS"                  #Assign DEHNSname to the name of Deformation Horizontal NS variable with corresponding to building's name
        
        if NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":         #Conditional for all prisms inputs are not empty
            DEHNS="("+"("+"Y"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Y"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"("+"Y"+str(NE_Prism)+"+"+"Y"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)      #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism=="":       #Conditional for SE_Prism input box is empty       
            DEHNS="("+"("+"Y"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"Y"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"Y"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)    #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism=="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NE_Prism input box is empty
            DEHNS="("+"("+"Y"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"Y"+str(NW_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"Y"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)    #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS
        
        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for SW_Prism input box is empty
            DEHNS="("+"Y"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"("+"Y"+str(SE_Prism)+"+"+"Y"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)    #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NW_Prism input box is empty
            DEHNS="("+"Y"+str(SW_Prism)+"-"+"("+"Y"+str(NE_Prism)+"+"+"Y"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)    #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS

        elif NW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SW_Prism=="" and SE_Prism=="":       #Conditional for SW_Prism and SE_Prism input boxes are empty
            DEHNS="("+"Y"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"Y"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)  #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism=="" and SW_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NW_Prism and NE_Prism input boxes are empty
            DEHNS="("+"Y"+str(SW_Prism)+"-"+"Y"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(NS_Distance)  #Assign DEHNS as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal NS

        VVList=[Station_ID,DEHNSname,Variable_ID,101,DEHNS]         #Put Station_ID,DEHNSname,Variable_ID,101,DEHNS into VVList of current input
        VVListofLists.append(VVList)                                #Append VVList to VVListofLists

    else:                       #Conditional for Deformation Horizontal NS calculation is not possible
        DEHNS=""            #Set DEHNS as blank
        DEHNSname=""        #Set DEHNSname as blank

    if (NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="") or (NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!=""):          #Conditional for Deformation Horizontal OE calculation is possible
        DEHOEname=Building_callsign + "DEH_OE"                                      #Assign DEHOEname to the name of Deformation Horizontal OE variable with corresponding to building's name
        
        if NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":         #Conditional for all prisms inputs are not empty
            DEHOE="("+"("+"X"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"X"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"("+"X"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"X"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)      #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism=="":       #Conditional for SE_Prism input box is empty
            DEHOE="("+"("+"X"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"X"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"X"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)        #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism=="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NE_Prism input box is empty
            DEHOE="("+"X"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"("+"X"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"X"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)        #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE
        
        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for SW_Prism input box is empty
            DEHOE="("+"("+"X"+str(NW_Prism)+"+"+"X"+str(NE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+"-"+"X"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)        #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NW_Prism input box is empty
            DEHOE="("+"X"+str(NE_Prism)+"-"+"("+"X"+str(SW_Prism)+"+"+"X"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+"2"+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)        #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE

        elif NW_Prism!="" and SW_Prism!="" and NE_Prism=="" and SE_Prism=="":       #Conditional for NE_Prism and SE_Prism input boxes are empty
            DEHOE="("+"X"+str(NW_Prism)+"-"+"X"+str(SW_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)      #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE
        
        elif NW_Prism=="" and SW_Prism=="" and NE_Prism!="" and SE_Prism!="":       #Conditional for NW_Prism and SW_Prism input boxes are empty
            DEHOE="("+"X"+str(NE_Prism)+"-"+"X"+str(SE_Prism)+")"+"/"+str(WE_Distance)      #Assign DEHOE as the calculation for Deformation Horizontal OE

        VVList=[Station_ID,DEHOEname,Variable_ID,101,DEHOE]         #Put Station_ID,DEHOEname,Variable_ID,101,DEHOE into VVList of current input
        VVListofLists.append(VVList)                                #Append VVList to VVListofLists
        
    else:                   #Conditional for Deformation Horizontal OE calculation is not possible
        DEHOE=""            #Set DEHOE as blank
        DEHOEname=""        #Set DEHOEname as blank    

    for a_list in VVListofLists:     #Loop for each list in VVListofLists
        insert(*a_list)              #Call the insert function with arguments based of items in a_list   

    
    return TasGLO, Tassgloname, TasDifNS, TasDifNSname, TasDifOE, TasDifOEname, DEHNS, DEHNSname, DEHOE, DEHOEname

def insert(Station_ID,Virtual_Variable,Variable_ID,Unit_ID,Formula):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO calculation VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,0,0,1,3600,1,3600,0,\"0000-00-00 00:00:00\",0,\"\")",(Station_ID,Virtual_Variable,Variable_ID,Unit_ID,Formula))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM calculation")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def drop():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE calculation")
    conn.close()

def Search(Virtual_Variable):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM calculation WHERE Variable LIKE ?",(Virtual_Variable+"%",))
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def delete(id):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM calculation WHERE id=?",(id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def export():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    sql = """
    SELECT
    Station_ID,
    '"' || COALESCE(Variable, '') || '"' Variable,
    Variable_ID,
    Unit_ID,
    '"' || COALESCE(Formula, '') || '"' Formula,
    RoC_Active,
    RoC_Precision,
    RoC_Period_Value,
    RoC_Period_Type,
    RoC_Unit_Value,
    RoC_Unit_Type,
    Datum_Variable_ID,
    '"' || COALESCE(Datum_Timestamp, '') || '"' Datum_Timestamp,
    '"' || COALESCE(Datum_Information, '') || '"' Datum_Information,
    '"' || COALESCE(Constants, '') || '"' Constants
    FROM calculation 
    """
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    csv_path = "output.csv"
    with open(csv_path, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter=";",quotechar='',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        # Write headers.
        csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
        # Write data.
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)

def update(id,Station_ID,Virtual_Variable,Formula):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE calculation SET Station_ID=?, Variable=?, Formula=? WHERE id=?",(Station_ID,Virtual_Variable,Formula,id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


connect()
```

You can try the data entry as following:

```
Building callsign: testing
All Prisms: Z101+Z102+Z103+Z104
NW Prism: Z101
NE Prism: Z102
SW Prism: Z103
SE Prism: Z104
NS Distance: 20
WE Distance: 12
Station ID: 1234
```

Then click Add Entry - View All, the data is populated as below:
[image]

The user can delete one data row at a time by selecting the row in the listbox then pressing Delete button. This might cause inconvenient for users if they want to delete multiple rows.

Is it possible to implement multiple deletion ? If it is possible, how can I do it via tkinter ?

Comment: You can use `DELETE FROM some_table WHERE some_field IN (v1, v2, v3)` to delete multiple records in database.

Comment: The users would like to delete multiple entries by selecting rows which they want to remove. However, the code above can only delete one row at a time. I can pass SQL query to delete but to implement it with tkinter for the given purpose is where I am perplexed.

Comment: The general solution is already mentioned above

Comment: The issue is that I do not know how to pass multiple ids from listbox selection to the DELETE queries of backendv2 module.

Comment: Are you able to select multiple items from listbox?

Comment: Aye, but it only return one id even I select 3 or 4 entries.

Comment: So, is the actual question you're asking is how to get the ids of more than one selected item from the listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already used `selectmode=EXTENDED` in `list1`, so you can select multiple items.

Below is an example on deleting multiple selected items:

*backendv2* module:

```py
def delete_many(id_list):
    placeholders = ', '.join('?'*len(id_list))
    sql = f"DELETE FROM calculation WHERE id IN ({placeholders})"
    print(sql, id_list)
    # cur.execute(sql, id_list)
```

*main* module:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import backendv2

selected_id_list = []

def get_selectd_row(event):
    global selected_id_list
    selected_id_list = [list1.get(index)[0] for index in list1.curselection()]
    print(selected_id_list)

def delete_command():
    if selected_id_list:
        backendv2.delete_many(selected_id_list)
        # remove items from listbox
        for item in list1.curselection()[::-1]:
            list1.delete(item)

root = tk.Tk()

list1 = tk.Listbox(root, width=20, selectmode=tk.EXTENDED)
list1.pack()
list1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_selectd_row)

# insert dummy items
for i in range(1, 11):
    list1.insert("end", (i, 1234, f"Item_{i}", ""))

tk.Button(root, text="Delete", command=delete_command).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

You can also use `backendv2.delete()` as below:

```py
def delete_command():
    if selected_id_list:
        for id in selected_id_list:
            backendv2.delete(id)
        # remove items in listbox
        for item in list1.curselection()[::-1]:
            list1.delete(item)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But your solution works like a charm. You helped dozen folks from wasting thousand of hours on data entries. Thank you.